# Both of my alert dialogs are showing when I press a button for one in my Android Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I have an activity with a menu inflator. There are two items which each should open there own dialog box. However when I press one both dialogs are opened on top of each other.

One of the two of the below classes are used depending on the button pressed. This is the execution line in the menu switch/case

```
case R.id.action_vote:
            VoteDialog.voteDialogShow(this);            

        case R.id.action_admin:
            AdminDialog.adminDialogShow(this);
```

These are the two dialog classes.. I removed some of the code for readability.

```
public class AdminDialog {

    public static void adminDialogShow(final Context context){

        final AlertDialog.Builder adminAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        adminAlert.setTitle("Restricted Area!");
        adminAlert.setMessage("Enter Access Code:");

        adminAlert.setView(input);
        //....
        //Setup text and buttons......
        //....
        adminAlert.show();
    }
}

public class VoteDialog {

    public static void voteDialogShow(final Context context){

        final AlertDialog.Builder voteAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        //....
        //Setup text and buttons......
        //....

        voteAlert.setView(input);

        //....

        voteAlert.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need `break`s in your `case`s. Otherwise, execution falls through to the next `case`/`default`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to:

```java
case R.id.action_vote:
    VoteDialog.voteDialogShow(this);    
    break;        

case R.id.action_admin:
    AdminDialog.adminDialogShow(this);
    break;
```

As pointed out by Mike M., you're missing the `break;` for each case in your switch to mark where its efects end. More details at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html